# Postfix After-Queue Content Filter doesn't work

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, mail-server, postfix-mta

i added the following line to the postfix master.cf

```
filter unix - n n - 10 pipe flags=Rq user=filter null_sender= argv=/tmp/filter.sh -f ${sender} -- ${recipient}
```

my test script filter.sh code looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
SENDMAIL="/usr/sbin/sendmail -G -i" # NEVER NEVER NEVER use "-t" here.
export HOME=/home/filter
SENDER="$2" #sender
shift
shift
shift
EMPFAENGER="$@" #empfaenger
#echo "SENDER=$SENDER" >> /tmp/logging.log
#echo "EMPFAE=$EMPFAENGER" >> /tmp/logging.log
touch itworked
cat | $SENDMAIL -f $SENDER -- $EMPFAENGER
```

When i send an email it will be delivered, but i its not piped through the script.

Does anybody know what i configured wrong?

PS:

- The user "filter" exists and he has all permissions to the script.
- Ubuntu 16.04.1
- Installed newest Mailcow use it only local

Greetings
Chris

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a step. In your configuration file `master.cf`, the first service is:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
```

you have to tell `postfix` you want to use your `filter`, so:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd -o content_filter=filter
```

Do not forget to execute `postfix reload` after editing this file.